# Unable to acces Nagios from Ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, http, nagios, curl

I have installed Nagios by following this tutorial [here](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/10/27/running-nagios-on-ec2/).

But when I tried to connect to `localhost/nagios3` using `curl` from console, making sure that Nagios is installed and running(since I'm getting an output stating that authorization required).

But when I tried to connect to :

> http://i-cXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com/nagios3/

I'm getting page not found error!

What went wrong?

Comment: why a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting to

```
http://i-cXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com/nagio3/
```

Than add a little s:

```
http://i-cXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com/nagios3/
```

Is it a spelling mistake?

Use:

```
curl --user name:password http://i-cXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com/nagios3/ --location
```

To authenticate with curl if you want to check if it is giving the correct output

Comment: No its not a spelling mistake. `curl` utility is working with provided user name and password.

Comment: I dont get it... you are saying that `localhost/nagios3` is working but `http://i-cXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com/nagio3/` is not working and giving you 404. Well if there is no virtual host with alias for nagio3 you will receive just that. Are you saing that you have two virtual hosts? One for nagios3 and one with nagio3 ? What for?

Comment: Sorry that was being my spelling mistake. ` localhost/nagios3` this works. And I have only one virtual host. so `http://i-cxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/nagios3/` is not working. Thats my problem.

Comment: 1. check if `amazonaws.com` is working
2. check if `compute.amazonaws.com` is working
3. check if `i-cxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com` is working
4. check if `http://i-cxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com` or `https://i-cxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com` is working

Comment: I guess the problem might be because, I'm running my instance inside a VPC. I guess this is causing problems for me. Are there any way to disable my instance from vpc and then add it back?

Comment: thats totally different question. I'm not familiar. maybe someone else will be able to answer that.

Comment: this sounds like an apache vhost configuration problem to me